# Unlimited Loop While In Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I Get an unlimited While Loop In python here's The Code For My Rolling Dice 
It keeps Rolling The Dice Over and over Again 
the Code :

```
#!usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import time
import sys
print ("")
print ("This is a dice rolling simulator ")
x=raw_input("press Enter to launch the dice ")
def dice():
    print("\nRolling the dice...\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    n=random.randint(1, 6)
    if n == 1:
        print '''
1
            '''
    if n == 2:
        print '''

            '''
    if n == 3:
        print '''
3
            '''
    if n == 4:
        print '''
4
            '''
    if n == 5:
        print '''
5
            '''
    if n == 6:
        print '''
6
            '''

dice()
x=raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
while x!= ("q"):
    dice()
if x== ("q"):
        print ("see you later ")
```

Comment: You should put the code in the question directly,not through a link to an external resource

Comment: it seems that you modify x outside of your loop that check x value.

Comment: @AnandSKumar i'm A Beginner and There's an Error While Putting the Code I'll Try

Comment: @Baart Thanks I'll Do It For Now It Works Fine I'll Improve It

Comment: @Hassene-Senpai keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to put the `raw_input()` function inside the while loop at line 40.

```
x=raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
while x!= ("q"):
    dice()
    x=raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not reading the input in the while loop. You should read it in the while loop so in each iteration you will be able to change it otherwise it will always do the same calculation.

You loop should look liek this:

```
x=raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
while x!= ("q"):
    dice()
    x=raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the user input inside the while loop... instead of

```
x = raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
while x != ("q"):
    dice()
```

try:

```
x = raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
while x != ("q"):
    dice()
    x = raw_input("press Enter to restart the or type q to quit")
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers that are telling you to duplicate your code are bad. Pythonic solution is

```
while True:
    dice()
    x = ...
    if x == 'q': break
```

In this case, you can also just set `x=''` at the beginning, but generally, there's nothing wrong with a loop that exits somewhere else than at the beginning.